# How to duplicate Django Celery worker?

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I have a logger in Celery (with RabbitMQ) and want to duplicate its work for emergency cases.

```
# tasks.py
@task
def log(message):
    with open('test.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(message)


# views.py
log.delay(message)
```

How can I make 2 instances of Celery on different machines run `log()` when it's called?

Does it make sense at all to do this?

This is possible in RabbitMQ. If you have a [topic-based exchange](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html), it's clear that one message can be put into two different queues and delivered independently to 2 receivers.

```
sender =>
[message, routing_key=event.logging.log] => [queue A, topic=event.#]     
                                                      => receiver 1
                                         => [queue B, topic=*.logging.*]
                                                      => receiver 2
```

The message will be sent to both queues, and none of them will steal the message from another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you would have to configure the exchange to be a topic exchange (as you say):

```
CELERY_QUEUES = {
   'celery': {
       'exchange': 'celerytopic',
       'exchange_type': 'topic',
       'routing_key': 'celery',
   },
}
```

Then you can create your backup exchange using the AMQP api:

```
 from celery import current_app as celery

 with celery.broker_connection() as conn:
     conn.default_channel.queue_declare(queue='celery.backup', durable=True)
     conn.default_channel.queue_bind(queue='celery.backup',
                                     exchange='celerytopic',
                                     routing_key='celery',
                                     durable=True)
```

Since you already have a queue named celery you may have to delete that first:

```
$ camqadm queue.delete celery
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense for me to try to start this task on two different machines. At least Celery cannot guarantee that a task will be run on different machines - it is RabbitMQ that distributes load, and if one node is less loaded than other - the two tasks run will be probably executed on that machine...

Use [task.`retry`](http://celery.github.com/celery/reference/celery.app.task.html#module-celery.app.task) instead. Celery will retry a task, if it fails to execute. Celery is smart enough to understand if a task had failed. Just make sure to raise some exception if the tasks fail, and not to return silently if it cannot successfully log.

UPDATE:

A possible workflow could be - try to execute the task, if it fails, in on_retry change the routing_key, and try to execute task in a different exchange/queue which can be your fail-over queue.

Comment: I'll add a comment on RabbitMQ.

Comment: My point was that you cannot choose which node will execute a task, in case of a simple load-balancing between equally configured nodes. At least this is the usual fail-over behavior. If you limit your tasks to run on certain nodes - then you automatically lose fail-over, and you're bound to the selected nodes. If all of them die.. You'll still have running nodes, but will not use them.  Or simply said - if it's gonna fail - you will hardly achieve flexibility with starting 2 simultaneous tasks.. You'd go after a safer approach - i.e. using the on_retry() function, to handle retries.

Comment: One small update to the answer. Moreover - using the proper return values, you can raise the actual exception and send it to another queue. Imagine you are out of disk space on your machines, no retry will work anyway. But a fail-over with sending email with the actual error, i.e. 'DISK FULL' makes much more sense in terms of emergency.